# How do I upload to paperclip asynchronously using backburner?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, delayed-job, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to upload a bunch of files into my server using paperclip. Currently it is too slow and hence i want to allocate this to my background workers. I am already using backburner for a bunch of tasks. I tried the following which does not work

```
upload = UploadedFile.async.create(params[:file])
```

The async function works will all other normal jobs but does not work with paperclip.

I read that i could use [delayed_job](http://mattgrande.com/2009/08/11/delayedjob/) . However since i am already using backburner which seems to do the same worker allocation, i ideally want to use that. If it is not possible, is it wise to use both backburner and delayed_job at the same time? Will there be any conflict in worker allocationwhen both are called at the same time for different processes on the server?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not experienced with backburner, but.

Uploading files in background is quite strange requirement.

Just imagine, while you are uploading file - browser keeps connection with server to transfer data.

Processing in background means, that you are immediately break this connection. It does not make sense, because you could not transfer file data in such way.

So uploading is synchronous operation, and can't be done in background.

Comment: I agree , i is just that it is crashing my browser for folders even as big as 50 mb. the only javascript i have is an upload bar which seems to be reason for the crash since it is happening through the main worker as well i guess.

Comment: the trick with the server connection is to have the user upload to s3 (or similar) with an ajax request instead, and do your processing / import as a background job.